# Setting how the number of plotted points Rickshaw.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

In [Rickshaw.js](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/), I am trying to plot a graph with 100 points, but only 10 show up in the graph, and the points in between the time points are ignored and simply interpolated. How can I control how many points show up on the graph?

Comment: A look at the code would help.